# How can I disable auto prefill of the editor's find/search box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if I press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search, it auto prefills the search box with the word under the cursor.  Is there a way to disable that behavior?

Comment: "_it auto prefills the search box with the word under the cursor_" Did you mean "the text selection"? Or does it really prefill it with the word the caret is on without selecting the text of that word? Because I'm not aware of that being a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the editor finder (AKA "search"), put the following in your settings.json:

```json
"editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection": "never"
```

The setting's description:

> Controls whether the search string in the Find Widget is seeded from the editor selection.

Bonus material: For the search panel in the sidebar (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> / `View: Show Search`), put the following in your settings.json:

```json
"search.seedOnFocus": true,
// "search.seedWithNearestWord": true, // optional
```